# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Data has no column named _Y

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem using my database. Please check this:

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Poloha";

// Data table name
private static final String DATA = "Data";

// Data Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_Y= "Y";
private static final String KEY_X= "X";
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAZEV = "Nazev";
private static final String KEY_MAC = "MAC";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" 
            + DATA + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
            + KEY_NAZEV + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_MAC + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
            + KEY_X + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
            + KEY_Y + " TEXT NOT NULL);" ;
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

Now I want to add some values using:

```
db.pridejZaznam(new Data(1,1,1,"NAZEV_1","MAC_1"));
db.pridejZaznam(new Data(2,2,2,"NAZEV_2","MAC_2"));
db.pridejZaznam(new Data(3,3,3,"NAZEV_3","MAC_3"));
db.pridejZaznam(new Data(4,4,4,"NAZEV_4","MAC_4"));
```

Problem is, LogCat is showing me this error:

```
02-22 10:33:26.336: E/SQLiteLog(813): (1) table Data has no column named Y
02-22 10:33:26.375: E/SQLiteDatabase(813): Error inserting Y=1 MAC=MAC_1 Nazev=NAZEV_1 _id=1 X=1
02-22 10:33:26.375: E/SQLiteDatabase(813): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Data has no column named Y (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Data(Y,MAC,Nazev,_id,X) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Any idea what should I do? I´ve check similar errors and found only a solution with a missing SPACE while creating table but if I´m not blind, I have it without anything missing. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" 
            + DATA + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," // and auto increment will be handled with                            primary key
            + KEY_NAZEV + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_MAC + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
            + KEY_X + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
            + KEY_Y + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to add KEY_ID, database will add it automatically, remove first value from your insert query :

> db.pridejZaznam(new Data(1,1,"NAZEV_1","MAC_1"));

and so on..

and use english names for methods and variables for better underdstanding

Comment: Thanks, problem is my database is defined this way:
    public Data(long id, String nazev, String MAC,int x,int y)
after few changes and it wants all 5 variables to be inserted. How can I force it to add ID automaticaly?

Comment: Saved my days.. I was doing the same mistake - passing the ID but I think it is not required. Database automatically adds key.

Answer (score 1):

You need space between the keyword `EXISTS` and the table name here:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" 
        + DATA + "("
```

change to:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
        + DATA + "("
```

After editing the table schema, uninstall your app so the `onCreate()` gets run again. See also: [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove the app and install it again.**

The MYSQLite table is stored in the local device and it does not append the tables